# Using DateTime to add numerous dates and times together

Tags: php

I was comparing start and end times from my database. I was finally able to figure that out, but now i need to add the times together to get a total of all the time differences. What is the best/fastest way to do that? I have never used DateTime before. 
Would i add something like `$date->add($interval)` into my while loop? I cannot figure out the proper way to implement it.
`$starttime` var example: 11:03:52 AM
`$startdate` var example: 08-16-2016
`$endtime` var example: 08:04:53 AM
`$enddate` var example: 08-17-2016

```
$start = $startdate." ".$starttime;
$end = $enddate." ".$endtime;

$start_formatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y g:i:s A', $start);
$started_on = $start_formatted->format("m-d-Y g:i:s A");

$end_formatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y g:i:s A', $end);
$ended_on = $end_formatted->format("m-d-Y g:i:s A");

$interval=$start_formatted->diff($end_formatted);

$intervalTypes = array("y", "m", "d", "h", "i", "s");
$intervalDescription = array("years", "months", "days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds");
$intervalLength = count($intervalTypes);
$intervalCounter = 0;



while ($intervalCounter < $intervalLength) {

$currentInterval = $intervalTypes[$intervalCounter];

if ($interval->$currentInterval != 0) {
    if ($interval->$currentInterval > 1) {
            echo $interval->$currentInterval." ".$intervalDescription[$intervalCounter]." ";
        } else {
            echo $interval->$currentInterval." ".substr($intervalDescription[$intervalCounter], 0, -1)." ";
            }
}

$intervalCounter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a default dateTime set at a time. And another one set at the exact same time. Then you should just add your interval found to one of the two dateTime. In the end you will just have to call again the diff method to now the total time difference between the two.

Example :

```
$default = new DateTime("2000-01-01");
$total = new DateTime("2000-01-01");
```

Your code here, where you calculate all your interval

```
$total->add($interval);
```

At the end

```
$totalInterval = $default->diff($total);
```

Here you get a DateInterval containing the cumul of all the intervals